# How to enable ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS with Jackson ObjectMapper 2.12?

Tags: jackson-databind

This line of code gives a deprecation warning:

```
mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS, true);
```

And this doesn't compile

```
mapper.configure(JsonReadFeature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS, true);
```

because `JsonReadFeature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS` not a subclass of any of the four `Feature` types `ObjectMapper` supports.

What is the correct was to enable this feature with Jackson 2.12?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any API that accepts `JacksonFeature` or `JsonReadFeature` as parameter.

`DeserializationConfig` accepts `FormatFeature` as parameter but you can't change this property of `ObjectMapper` after getting a new instance by calling `withFeatures()`.

The only solutions seems to be to get the feature out of the `JsonReadFeature` which is then no longer deprecated:

```
mapper.enable(JsonReadFeature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS.mappedFeature());
```

(note the method call at the end of the enum).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen such error in vert.x. The following line helped.
`DatabindCodec.mapper().configure(JsonReadFeature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS.mappedFeature(), true);`

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the `ObjectMapper.setConfig()` methods are not deprecated and can be used to rewrite the configuration (of both serializer and deserializer, separately), and the `SerializationConfig` and `DeserializationConfig` classes can be manipulated without deprecation warnings.

I have found no other way to modify the Vert.x `DatabindCodec` mappers, as the "recommended" way to configure mapper according to the current Jackson documentation is to create new mappers as needed.

So the code to implement the OP should be something like this:

```java
DatabindCodec.mapper().setConfig(
        DatabindCodec.mapper().getDeserializationConfig()
        .with(JsonReadFeature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS));
```